# Jquery, javascript - Picking a specific 2d array to use depending on other variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my project I'm using 2d arrays to append specific divs in specific cases. I tried to make the code more clean and usable few times on 1 site i decided to create a variable that would show which array should be used depending on html `<div>` id.

For example

```
if div id="ruby"
```

I want to

```
console.log(ruby[1][1]), 

if div="rails" 
I want to console.log(rails[1][1]).
```

I created a JS fiddle that should show you what problem I have with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/6UgeB/

```
var ruby = [[1,2,3],
            [4,5,6]];
var rails = [[7,8,9],
             [10,11,12]];
$("div").each(function () {
    currentDiv = $(this);
    currentDivID = currentDiv.attr("id");
    console.log(currentDivID);
    /* HAVE TO SOMEHOW COMPARE THE currentDivID TO OTHER VARIABLE NAMES AND IF IT FITS SWITCH THE currentDivID WITH THE EARLIER SET VARIABLE */
    console.log(currentDivID[1][1]);
    /* THE ABOVE SHOULD RETURN IF currentDivID = ruby 5 OR 11 if currentDivID = rails */
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a lookup object that maps a string to an array:

```
var map = { ruby : ruby, rails : rails };
```

Now you can use the object to get the array:

```
console.log(map[currentDivID][1][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your arrays in an object:

```
var tables = {
    ruby: [[1,2,3],
          [4,5,6]],
    rails: [[7,8,9],
            [10,11,12]]
};
```

You can then use:

```
tables[currentDivID][1][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Javascript **eval** method

```
eval(currentDivID)[1][1];
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/tleish/6UgeB/1/